# Get all CSS variables on root that source from an imported stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to get all of the CSS variables availalbe in my page's root element, but I'm running into problem due to how I'm importing the styles.

I have the following in my page head:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import 'shared/css/variables.css';

    //... Additional styles here
</style>
```

Within the `variables.css` file exists a number of CSS variables:

```
:root {
  --var-name-1: blue;
  --var-name-2: red;
}
```

I'm attempting to get all of the variables within `:root` as an array using the following script:

```
const css = [].slice
    .call(document.styleSheets)
    .map(styleSheet => [].slice.call(styleSheet.cssRules))
    .flat()
    .filter(cssRule => cssRule.selectorText === ':root');

console.log(css);
```

This script doesn't seem to work and returns `[]`, however if I inline the contents of  `variables.css` within the style tag it seems to work. Is there a way I can modify my script to make it work with imported stylesheets, or do I need to do some sort of pre-processing with Webpack to inline its contents?

Strangely I am able to use `getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('--var-name-1');` and it does resolve no matter how I import the variables stylesheet, so I feel like there must be a way?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your javascript in `window.onload = function() {}`? Since you are refencing `document.styleSheets`, maybe that CSS file hasn't been loaded before the javascript is ran.

Comment: I did, same thing though - just an empty array. I tried a few other things too such as wrapping the statement in a setTimeout, and checking for the documents ready state. For whatever reason it always returns an empty array even though an element is rendered on the page using the same variables.

Comment: I know this is quite specific so it probably won't work for you but I was able to get root by doing this: `const css = [].slice
    .call(document.styleSheets)
    .map(styleSheet => [].slice.call(styleSheet.cssRules)).flat();

   console.log(css[0].parentStyleSheet.cssRules[0].styleSheet.rules[0].cssText);`